# Update mutiple documents using update_by_query API?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using update_by_query we can update only existing fields that are present in mappings or we can able to create a new field with a value in all documents..

Because i tried the following query for creating a new field in all documents in the index:

```
  {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "uniqueId": 805569568956
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.Univesity.Name.Region.Europe = 'UCLA'"
  }
}
```

IT throws an error like this

```
     {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "failed to run inline script [ctx._source.Univesity.Name.Region.Europe = 'UCLA'] using lang [groovy]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "failed to run inline script [ctx._source.Univesity.Name.Region.Europe = 'UCLA'] using lang [groovy]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "null_pointer_exception",
      "reason": "Cannot get property 'Name' on null object"
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

In elasticsearch.yaml i configured the following properties:

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs:  on
script.engine.groovy.inline:          true
```

My mapping is something like this:

```
"mappings": {
         "Univesity": {
            "properties": {
               "Name": {
                  "properties": {
                     "Region": {
                        "properties": {
                           "Europe": {
                              "type": "string"
                           }
                           "Australia": {
                              "type": "string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
```

Comment: In 5.0.0 and in 5.2, the query I wrote below works (tested on Windows and Linux). So far, since you're not showing everything I can only infer something is wrong from your "filtered" query or your "missing" query

Comment: I updated my question based on your feedback..Can you please go through that..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes, otherwise the Elasticsearch engine is going to look for a variable called UCLA. Your inline script should rather look like:

```
"script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.University.collegename = 'UCLA'"
}
```

(Notice the simple quotes around UCLA)

Edit: See a full working query example:

```
POST employeeid/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query":{
    "match": {
      "name": "Sam"
    }
  },
  "script":{
    "inline": "ctx._source.importance2 = 2000"
  }
}
```

Also be careful as the doc mentions this update by query is still experimental (see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update-by-query.html):

> The update-by-query API is new and should still be considered experimental.

Comment: Thanks..using your script i can able to get response without any error but i didn't see any document updated.

Comment: Do you have any match with your query? Are you using the correct protocol?

Comment: yes in my document i have exact field ` "uniqueId": 589568` .

Comment: What protocol do you use with your query? It's not shown on your question

Comment: You mean HTTP. I use POST

Comment: Check that in a search, you have actually a document returned. I encountered the same issue by believing my query was returning a document when it was not... Also can you confirm your query somehow looks like the one in my edit?

Comment: As you said,Even a small query similar to the one which you had given also not updating anything .May i know why?

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of the query ?